# Mysql QUERY HoW DO I query the sting contain in sequence

Tags: mysql

sample my table field contains the text

table data

| name | route |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | data1 data2 data6 data7 |
| A2 | data7 data6 data5 data4 data2 |
| A3 | data2 data5 data6 data7 data8 data9 |
| A4 | data1 data2 data7 |
| A5 | data1 data2 data4 data6 data7 |

how do we query tho show the field contains data2 and data7 in sequence
sample output

| name | route |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | data1 **data2** data6 **data7** |
| A3 | **data2** data5 data6 **data7** data8 data9 |
| A4 | data1 **data2** **data7** |
| A5 | data1 **data2** data4 data6 **data7** |

line 2 not include because data7 and data2 not in sequence
help anyone ...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How does that table look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: SELECT data
FROM route
WHERE route LIKE '%data2%' AND routeLIKE '%data7%';

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Anything not working with the shared query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIKE operator:

```
SELECT yourcolumn 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE '%data2%' AND yourcolumn LIKE '%data7%';
```

Comment: ....unless somebody adds `data21` to the column

Comment: << data1 data2 data4 data6 data7>>

Comment: i have change the view for table hope it clear what my meannin sequence

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it`s the perfect solution.

Select * from table having data2 and data 7.(use query).
Loop to every single data.
explode the value by  and check if data2 exists before data7.
If the condition is met create new array and push this element to the new array.
[Click here to check sample code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awOZ7.png)

Comment: Please mark code as code and separate it from the description. The current answer is unclear at a glance.

Comment: Please share more details. "Having data2 and data7" does not sound like a valid MySQL query. Also, why did you write PHP code for a MySQL question?